# Apache Nutch url's in regex-urlfilter.txt file

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to crawling and specially apache nutch. The configuration for apache nutch is really complex. I have been researching a lot through apache nutch and came up to the regex-urlfilter.txt file where you have to mention that which pages, you want to crawl and to limit your crawling. Since, there is not a good/simple tutorial about this that's why I am here. The explanation of the Question is given below.

Explanation

Suppose I have a website named as `https://www.example.com`. Now in order to crawl only this website and limit my crawl I know I have to edit my regex-urlfilter.txt file like this `+^https://www.example.com/` Now what If I want to limit this more? For example, I only want to crawl some of the pages from this given website.

```
https://www.example.com/something/details/1
https://www.example.com/something/details/2
https://www.example.com/something/details/3
https://www.example.com/something/details/4
https://www.example.com/something/details/5
.
.
.
https://www.example.com/something/details/10
```

P.S: As a new member, I may have made a lots of mistake in asking a good question. Please, help me to improve the question, instead of giving -1. I will be really thankful to you all.

Comment: what do you mean by "some of the pages". For regular expression you'll need a rule. It can be a list ids that you want to allow, greater than, less than etc

Comment: @aelor I want to limit my crawl to some pages of the site. For example, I only want the data from the given url, lets say ```www.example.com```. So instead of crawling whole of the site, I only want to crawl ```www.example.com/something/details/``` all the pages after slash (/), nothing else. I read that you can limit your crawl with regular expression, but don't have any idea, How to mention that..

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to crawl `https://www.example.com/something/details/` and below, replace the last line of regex-urlfilter.txt from:

```
# accept anything else
+.
```

To:

```
+https://www.example.com/something/details/
-.
```

That will include only URLs that contain `https://www.example.com/something/details/`, and ignore all other URLs.